# SAPUI5: Adding Cells with Header Items

Tags: javascript, xml, view, sapui5, xmltable

I have a question regarding the Syntax of how to add a Item to the table that does have 4 different nested Entities.

The modell looks as the following:

```
(3)[{...},{...},{...}]

0:{name:"Example1", 
  criteria:[      
    0:{description:"First Nested Item"}
    1:{description:"Second Nested Item"}
    2:{description:"Third Nested Item"}
    3:{description:"Fourth Nested Item"}
         ]
   },

1:{name:"Example2", 
  criteria:[      
    0:{description:"First Nested Item"}
    1:{description:"Second Nested Item"}
    2:{description:"Third Nested Item"}
    3:{description:"Fourth Nested Item"}
         ]
   },

2:{name:"Example3", 
  criteria:[      
    0:{description:"First Nested Item"}
    1:{description:"Second Nested Item"}
    2:{description:"Third Nested Item"}
    3:{description:"Fourth Nested Item"}
         ]
   }
```

**The Issue:** How should the **Syntax** look like in the **XML-View-Table**, so that i can achieve the following

**Example1**

"First Nested Item"

"Second Nested Item"

"Third Nested Item"

"Fourth Nested Item"

**Example2**

"First Nested Item"

"Second Nested Item"

"Third Nested Item"

"Fourth Nested Item"